# Schedule the Online Lync Meeting for anonymous users

Tags: lync, lync-2013, lync-server-2010

I have requirement to generate the url of the lync meeting for anonymous users or outsiders to view the video meeting without any invitation.

Answer (score 0):

Create the meeting then give them the link to the meeting, they can view it from any web browser as a guest.

Answer (score 0):

You can use UCMA to create a Lync meeting URL. Then use the meeting URL while scheduling the anonymous meeting.